# When you divide the polynomial $A(x)$ by $(x-1)(x+2)$, what remainder will you end up with?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

When you divide the polynomial $A(x)$ by $x-1$, you get a remainder of $10$. When you divide $A(x)$ by $x+2$ you get remainder $0$.

When you divide $A(x)$ by $(x-1)(x+2)$ what remainder will you end up with?

Comment: Possible abstract duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107507/what-is-the-remainder-when-polynomial-fx-is-divided-by-x1x-3-when-f?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Write
$$
A(x)=(x-1)(x+2)B(x)+C(x)\quad\text{where}\quad C(x)=ax+b.
$$
The question asks for $C(x)$ so you're to find $a$ and $b$. The given info tells you $C(1)=A(1)=10$ and $C(-2)=A(-2)=0$. So you have 2 unknowns $a$ and $b$ and 2 equations $C(1)=10$ and $C(-2)=0$. Can you proceed?

Comment: Okay, so I calculated values for $a$ and $b$, now how to calculate the actual remainder?

Comment: @Martez The remainder is $ax+b$.