# Factor/Remainder theorem question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When $h(x)$ is divided by $(x-1)$, it's remainder is$ -2$. When it is divided by $(x+3)$,the remainder is $10$. Find the remainder when $ h(x)$ is divided by $$(x-1)(x+3)$$.

What I did.

$$h(1)=-2$$

$$h(-3)=10$$

from $h(1)$ and $h(-3)$

$$h(x)=Q(x)(x-1)-2$$

$$h(x)=P(x)(x+3)-10$$

Then I don't really know what to do...

Comment: Similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1783960/321264, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1107507/321264

Comment: Oh sorry!Didn't know there was similar ones.